# Swift3 JSONSerialization with [String:Any] rather than NSDictionary

Tags: json, swift

Say you have a string of json `someText` and you want to parse it to a dictionary. Previously I have done this...

```
let jsonResult: NSDictionary =
   try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
      with: someText.data(using: .utf8)!,
      options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
         as! NSDictionary
```

but that's just a crappy `NSDictionary`.

It would seem that you can indeed do this......

```
let jsonResult: [String:Any] =
   try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
      with: someText.data(using: .utf8)!,
      options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
         as! [String:Any]
```

so that's now a real Swift dictionary.

Does this work?  Are there drastic efficiency differences, or perhaps other problems?

Confusingly to me,

```
  open class func jsonObject(with data: Data,
     options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any
```

the call just returns `Any` anyways.  So when you cast it to your `[String:Any]` or indeed `NSDictionary`, what's the process, what is best?

Comment: It should work, it returns Any, because the JSON could be at top level an Array. JSON are just Dictionary, Array, String and Numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Does this work?*" – did you try it?

Comment: Note that you don't need `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers` unless you plan on working with an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there drastic efficiency differences

Yes there are.

`NSDictionary` completely lacks type information, native Swift collection types are much more efficient and highly recommended. And you get mutability for free using `var`. `mutableContainers` are useless in Swift anyway.

`jsonObject(with data` returns `Any` because the return type can be `Dictionary`, `Array` or even `String/Number`, the least common denominator is `Any`, cast it to the expected type.

Comment: Fantastically knowledgeable answer, thanks.  So, in a word, [String:Any] is the way to go now - no need to use / don't use NSDictionary.

Comment: Yes, it is. Use `NSDictionary` only if you have absolutely no choice (for example a few CoreFoundation API)

Answer (score 3):

[`JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject) returns an `NSDictionary` in the case of parsing a JSON object (or an `NSMutableDictionary` in the case of `.mutableContainers` – but this is redundant for both of your examples).

However, its return is statically typed as `Any` due to the fact that other types can be returned depending on the JSON data type parsed. You therefore need to cast this result to a dictionary type in order to inform the compiler that the data you're parsing is in fact a valid JSON object (and of course if you're not sure of this fact, you should [*conditionally cast*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID341) to handle the case where it isn't).

When it comes to Swift dictionaries, there are two storage schemes that can be used – native or Cocoa. In the case of casting the result to a `[String : Any]`, you're *bridging* the `NSDictionary` over to a Swift dictionary using the Cocoa scheme – which is no more complicated than just a wrapper around the underlying `NSDictionary`.

From [HashedCollections.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L59):

> ```
> // Cocoa storage uses a data structure like this::
> //
> //   Dictionary<K,V> (a struct)
> //   +----------------------------------------------+
> //   | _VariantDictionaryBuffer<K,V> (an enum)     |
> //   | +----------------------------------------+   |
> //   | | [ _CocoaDictionaryBuffer (a struct) ] |   |
> //   | +---|------------------------------------+   |
> //   +-----|----------------------------------------+
> //         |
> //     +---+
> //     |
> //     V  NSDictionary (a class)
> //   +--------------+
> //   | [refcount#1] |
> //   +--------------+
> ```

Therefore, in terms of efficiency, there's no real difference between casting to `NSDictionary` or `[String : Any]`. You're still working with an `NSDictionary` either way.

However, as [@vadian has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41062096/2976878), a native Swift dictionary should *always* be preferred over a plain `NSDictionary` when working in Swift, as they actually carry type-information about its keys and values, which the compiler can statically enforce.

Comment: @JoeBlow In the case of parsing in dictionary JSON, `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` will output a `NSDictionary` (it's statically typed as `Any` because it could return other types of instances) – so it's not a case of the *bridge* making the `NSDictionary`, its `JSONSerialization` that makes the `NSDictionary`, which the bridge then wraps in a native Swift dictionary.

Comment: And yes, you *could* create your own fresh `[String : Any]` (which would use native storage) and do an O(n) operation to bridge over each individual key-value pair – however the motivation behind wrapping the `NSDictionary`, rather than doing that O(n) operation for you, is to allow for fast bridging from Obj-C in constant time. It will also allow you to bridge *back* to Obj-C in constant time.

Comment: Hi @Hamish.  Magnificent, thanks.  Something I don't understand .. could it be the case that "in the future" they rewrite JSONSerialization.jsonObject#withData so that it "really" builds and returns a [String:Any] , and has no connection to NSDictionary?  Or am I misunderstanding?  Looking at it another way, say for a large app I wrote my own parser function to read a string, and specifically return a [String:Any] in that use case.  Just to be utterly clear, I would be returning a "real" [String:Any] - nothing to do with NSDictionary. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @JoeBlow The problem is that `JSONSerialization` is really just the Swift name for `NSJSONSerialization` – which is a Foundation class, and therefore is implemented in Objective-C. Therefore, as it currently stands, there's no way for `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` to return a native Swift dictionary *directly*, as they don't exist in Objective-C. Apple would have to implement a completely new API in the Swift stdlib in order to allow for this. And yes, if you create a new `[String : Any]` yourself in Swift, as far as I understand, you'll be using the native scheme.

Comment: @JoeBlow Glad to be of help! Just as a side note, I wouldn't get too caught up with which scheme `Dictionary` is using – both the native scheme and Cocoa scheme will be well optimised to handle most (if not all) common use-cases. If you ever hit a bottleneck, you can always profile and test to see which scheme gives you better performance :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130234/discussion-between-hamish-and-joe-blow).

Comment: I sent you a 250 bounty as a token of thanks, thanks!  amazing answer